# In Vscode, how to change the default font size of markdown cell in a jupyter notebook

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, markdown

When I am using jupyter notebook in vscode, I suddenly find the default font size become so small. So how to make the default font size bigger in the markdown cell? I have tried to google how to fix the problem, but I can't find the answer. Looking forward to your reply!
[image]

Update：
After I added code`< font size=3 >` on the first line of each markdown cell, the display became normal. But I think I should not everytime do it because it is a  waste of time.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately there's no way to do this at the moment. Please upvote https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/126294 which tracks the feature request to allow configuring markdown font sizing.

Answer (score 1):

From https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/126294#issuecomment-964601412

> The next insiders build adds a new `notebook.markup.fontSize` setting
> which controls the size of rendered markdown
>
> It defaults to 120% of your editor font size (so 12px editor font size
> == 14.4px). We may adjust the default value based on feedback

And see [Adjust the font size in notebooks](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_63.md#adjust-the-font-size-in-notebooks)